# How to make toggle switch always ON in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toggleswitch

I want to make the state of toggle switch to ON always, even if user tries to make it OFF, it should not change. I tried to use .isUserInterstionEnabled = .false, but that didn't work. Can somebody help me on this? Thank you in advance

Comment: "but that didn't work" It worked for me...

Comment: Agreed. You need to show your code and explain what happens when you try to use `switch.isUserInterstionEnabled = false`. That's always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `toggle.isEnabled = false`

Comment: Setting isEnabled to false will also change the appearance to make it look dimmed. That might or might not be the result the OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

1.Make the switch outlet in the view controller.

2.Create `IBAction` of switch and set-:

```
self.swithCtrl.setOn(true, animated: false)
```

User will try to disable it but it will remain enable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I see you can achieve what you want.

1. Disable it, using the modifier `.disabled()` (the user will see it slightly faded):

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var isOn = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Text of toggle", isOn: $isOn)
                .disabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Force it to go back to on, using the modifier `.onChange(of:)`:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var isOn = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Text of toggle", isOn: $isOn)
        }
        .onChange(of: isOn) { _ in
            isOn = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is SwiftUI. The OP didn't mention SwiftUI.